# Use sentence transformers models with Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I have an apache beam pipeline that **works flawlessly** with a `DirectRunner`, **but not** with a `DataflowRunner` :

When using a DataflowRunner I get a `"Error 413 (Request entity too large)"`
From what I understand, it is because the pipeline file is too large. (I get it with the following option : `--dataflow_job_file=gs://...`
And this is caused by the model I use :

```
embeding_model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2')
```

Have anyone already experimented something similar ?

Comment: You reading your file with a `TextIO` or `FileIO` or you read your file in a `ParDo` transformation ?

Comment: I'm not reading any file, I query Big Query

Comment: hi @edWSA, Is your issue resolved? Have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#json-request-too-large) troubleshooting doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in the assumption that the pipeline file is too large--the direct runner doesn't have that limitation but I believe Dataflow limits the JSON to something like 20mb.

I'm guessing you're embedding the model into that JSON? You'll probably be better off loading it from an external source. For example, RunInference in the Python SDK allows for loading [custom models](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/beam-ml/run_custom_inference.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks for the hint !
I will dig this and come back here with the results

Comment: You can try to use the option `--experiments=upload_graph` to overcome the limit in the size of the job graph.

Comment: ok, so custom models as Byron said, RunInference are the solution, plus a setup.py file contaning REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    the lib you need
]